# how to save response to room database correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

Hi all I am developing news app I have implemented room database with kotlin coroutines what I want to achieve I want to  fetch data  first then that respose I want to save to room database but data not showing at all below my database implementation

```
@Database(entities = [Article::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(SourceTypeConverters::class)
abstract class SportNewsDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun sportNewsDao(): SportNewsDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: SportNewsDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance( context: Context): SportNewsDatabase? {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(SportNewsDatabase::class.java) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, SportNewsDatabase::class.java, "article_database")
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()
                }
            }
            return instance
        }
    }


}
```

SportNewsDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface SportNewsDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM  Article")
    fun getAllData(): LiveData<List<Article>>

    @Insert
    suspend fun addAll(article: List<Article>)


    @Update
    suspend fun updateArticle(article: Article)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteArticle(article: Article)

}
```

below NewsRepository.kt

```
class NewsRepository(private val sportNewsApi: SportNewsInterface, private val sportNewsDao: SportNewsDao) {

        val data = sportNewsDao.getAllData()

        suspend fun refresh() {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val articles = sportNewsApi.getNewsAsync().body()?.articles
                if (articles != null) {
                    sportNewsDao.addAll(articles)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

below MainViewModel.kt

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class MainViewModel(val newsRepository: NewsRepository) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
    // Coroutine's background job
    val job = Job()
    // Define default thread for Coroutine as Main and add job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job

    val showLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val sportList = MutableLiveData<List<Article>>()
    val showError = SingleLiveEvent<String>()

    fun loadNews() {
        // Show progressBar during the operation on the MAIN (default) thread
        showLoading.value = true
        // launch the Coroutine
        launch {
            // Switching from MAIN to IO thread for API operation
            // Update our data list with the new one from API
            val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                newsRepository?.data
                newsRepository.refresh()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know where I am making mistake what I have to do in order to save response to database correctly and show data to my android application.

Answer (score 0):

This my help you debug what is going on.
You can get the created DB file on your phone with the Device File Explorer

View -> Tool Windows -> Device File Explorer.

Then navigate to where your database is and download them on your pc.

Download a SQLite DB browser and inspect the DB.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I want save it to room database app not loading data at all it is showing empty white screen